# Maximum download counts -> then refresh page

Tags: jquery, html, page-refresh

I have a download page with a maximum download count of 5 for each file. Every download is linking to download.php?fileid. When clicked, the number of downloads is substracted with one in the database. But it's only updated when a visitor refreshes the page.

Now, I thought jQuery will help me out, and I have this now:

```
<span class="downloadsleft">5</span><span class="downloadLink">download file</span>
```

My jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">     
                $('.downloadLink').click(function() {

                        var currentValue = $(".amount").text();
                        var newValue = +currentValue - 1;

                        $(".amount").text(newValue);

                        window.open("download.php?file={/literal}{$product.bestandsnaam_hash}{literal}");                   

                        if ((".amount").text == "1")
                        {
                            location.reload();
                        };
                });  

            </script>
```

The window open works, but the reload doesn't work? Does anyone know this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Explanation

`.amount` isn't the good class name! use `.downloadsleft` instead!

Since `.amount` does not exist, there is **no initial value set** to the variable `currentValue`.

---

## Solution

([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lun471k/j8EV7/2/))

Replace all the `.amount` in your `JavaScript` code by `.downloadsleft`:

**NOTE**: I also added a `parseInt()` function in `base10` to compare the number of downloads to a number.

### JavaSript/jQuery

```
  $('.downloadLink').click(function() {
      var currentValue = $(".downloadsleft").text();
      var newValue = currentValue - 1;

      $(".downloadsleft").text(newValue);

      window.open("download.php?file={/literal}{$product.bestandsnaam_hash}{literal}");                

      if (parseInt(newValue,10) == 1)
      {
          location.reload();
      };
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

you are missing the () in the text

```
 if ((".amount").text() == "1")
```

you don't need to fetch the information again with query, it is already in the var newValue:

```
 if (newValue == 1)
```

**edit**: your code will only work for one download in the page because you are using the same ".amount" (i assume you meant ".downloadsleft") for all the downloads. One solution is to use the previous element intead of locating the element by class:

```
$('.downloadLink').click(function() {
      var counter = $(this).prev();
      var newValue = counter.text() - 1;
      counter.text(newValue);
      window.open("download.php?file={/literal}{$product.bestandsnaam_hash}{literal}");                   
      if (newValue == 1) {
          location.reload();
      };
});
```